# Refresh my mobile page when someone hits back button or do back swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code forwards when hitting back button:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
</script>
```

This back button refresh code works in iOS but not in Android:

```
<input type="hidden" id="refreshed" value="no">
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload=function(){
        var e=document.getElementById("refreshed");
        if(e.value=="no")e.value="yes";
        else{e.value="no";location.reload();}
    }
</script>
```

So what I want to know is can we mix both to work in every OS?

Can we implement any of these to first prevent back code to make it refresh?

```
    window.location.href = window.location.href; //This is a possibility
    window.location.reload(); //Another possiblity
    history.go(0); //And another
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.